# Trouble with loop inside loop inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

So I'm trying to make a simple validator to validate the user input towards a predefined array. When all the inputs are valid i want to let them "send" the input forward in my code.

The problem with the code is the loop. I have made 3 loops as following:

```
for (x = 0; x < validates.length; x++) {
    for (i = 0; i < validates[x].length; i++) {
        for (y = 0; y < inputs.length; y++) {
            console.warn(inputs[y]);
            console.warn(validates[x]);
             if (inputs[y].toLowerCase().indexOf(validates[x]) !== -1) {
                console.warn("vali1 == " + validates[x] + "!");
                 found += "t";
                break;
            }else {
                found += "f";
            }
        }break;
    }break;
}
```

[JsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/tcf6gg1b/)
I know that i could have made the code much easier by just making 3 separate loops of 1. But i want to move forward with my code to become a better writer.

So my question is why does this not work and why? Is there some alternatives or am i on the right track? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to write better, you should probably refactor this. Nested loops are not always the way to go.

Comment: don't use `console.warn` to output log into console

Comment: @captainrad So you'd say that just making for example 1 loop per input field would be a better way to  refactor it? :)

Comment: @Timh Never heard of flags, do you have any links for me to read? :)

Comment: @A.Wolff Is it bad to warn?

Comment: @BlitZz Not bad but that's not the purpose of it. Regarding your issue, i'm still not sure to see what is your expected behaviour because by breaking each loop, you get expected behaviour

Comment: What's the point of a loop that breaks after the first iteration with no conditional?

Comment: @A.Wolff I broke every loop so that i came closer my behaviour. my expected behaviour is that the loop first checks if input 1 == something in the region array then it does the same until there is no more inputs to check. Was it this you were confused about? :) or did it misunderstand you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient alternative is to refactor your code to reduce number of loops.

```
var valid_vals = { 'region': ["aridia", "black rise", "branch", "cache", "catch", "cloud ring", "cobalt edge", "curse", "deklein", "delve", "derelik", "detorid", "devoid", "domain", "esoteria", "essence", "etherium reach", "everyshore", "fade", "feythabolis", "fountain", "geminate", "genesis", "great wildlands", "heimatar", "immensea", "impass", "insmother", "kador", "khanid", "kor-azor", "lonetrek", "malpais", "metropolis", "molden heath", "oasa", "omist", "outer passage", "outer ring", "paragon soul", "period basis", "perrigen falls", "placid", "providence", "pure blind", "querious", "scalding pass", "sinq laison", "solitude", "stain", "syndicate", "tash-murkon", "tenal", "tenerifis", "the bleak lands", "the citadel", "the forge", "the kalevala expanse", "the spire", "tribute", "vale of the silent", "venal", "verge vendor", "wicked creek"],
    'ship': ["venture", "procurer", "retriever", "covetor", "skiff", "mackinaw", "hulk"],
    'ore': ["veldspar", "concentrated veldspar", "dense veldspar", "scordite", "condensed scordite", "massive scordite", "pyroxeres", "solid pyroxeres", "viscous pyroxeres", "plagioclase", "azure plagioclase", "rich plagioclase", "omber", "silvery omber", "golden omber", "kernite", "luminous kernite", "fiery kernite", "jaspet", "pure jaspet", "pristine jaspet", "hemorphite", "vivid hemorphite", "radiant hemorphite", "hedbergite", "vitric hedbergite", "glazed hedbergite", "gneiss", "iridescent gneiss", "prismatic gneiss", "dark ochre", "onyx ochre", "obsidian ochre", "spodumain", "bright spodumain", "gleaming spodumain", "crokite", "sharp crokite", "crystalline crokite", "bistot", "triclinic bistot", "monoclinic bistot", "arkonor", "crimson arkonor", "prime arkonor", "mercoxit", "magma mercoxit", "vitreous mercoxit"]
};

$("#check").click(function () {
    // validation code          
    var all_valid = true;

    $('input.validate').each(function () {
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), valid_vals[$(this).attr('id')]) === -1) {
            console.log($(this).attr('id') + ' did not validate');
            all_valid = false;
        }
    });

    if (all_valid)
        console.log("All fields validated");
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tcf6gg1b/2/

Comment: Interesting way of doing it! Don't understand what $.inArray does, but i'll research it! Thank you